# Get details from PKCS7 (CMS) via C++

Tags: c++, c, openssl, cryptography

I have `target.cert` file and want to get details like certificate endDate and startDate

```
openssl pkcs7 -in target.cert -inform DER -print_certs -out cert_pem

openssl x509 -in cert.pem -enddate -startdate -noout
```

and output is start and end date, and want to do same but from a C++ code.

```
FILE* fp;
if (!(fp = fopen("target.cert", "rb"))) { 
fprintf(stderr, "Error reading input pkcs7 file\n" ); 
exit(1); 
} 
PKCS7 *p7; 
p7 = d2i_PKCS7_fp(fp, NULL);
```

but `p7` has no fields like "startDate" or ability to parse fields.

How can I get "start/end dates" via C++?

Answer (score 0):

The start and end date are for the X.509 certificate that you have already extracted before from the PKCS#7 structure. So you have to do the same thing as for your command line:

1. extract certificate;
2. get the validity period by retrieving the start / *expiration* date.

PKCS#7 is a container format, which *may* just include certificates. However, PKCS#7 *is not* a certificate in the same way that a cookie jar is not a cookie, even if it just contains one cookie. So the name of your container, `target.cert` is very badly chosen and seems to wrongfoot even you. Commonly we use the extension `.p7` or `.pkcs7` instead.

Answer (score 0):

PKCS7 does not have a startDate/endDate. The certificates inside it do. You need to extract them first and ask them for the dates. Something like this should do the trick:

```
STACK_OF(X509) *certs = NULL;

// find out where the certs stack is located
int nid = OBJ_obj2nid(p7->type);
if(nid == NID_pkcs7_signed) {
    certs = p7->d.sign->cert;
} else if(nid == NID_pkcs7_signedAndEnveloped) {
    certs = p7->d.signed_and_enveloped->cert;
}

// go over all the certs in the chain (you can skip this and look only at the first 
// certificate if you don't care for the root CA's certificate expiration date)
for (int i = 0; certs && i < sk_X509_num(certs); i++)  {
    X509 *cert = sk_X509_value(certs, i);
    const ASN1_TIME *start = X509_get0_notBefore(cert);
    const ASN1_TIME *end = X509_get0_notAfter(cert);
    // do whatever you will with the dates
}
```